# Question regarding simple/compound/complex sentences

Tags: grammaticality

We read about these three classes of sentences. For example,

- It is too hot to go out without an umbrella. (Simple)
- It is so hot that we cannot go out without an umbrella. (Complex)
- It is very hot and so we cannot go out without an umbrella. (Compound)

My teacher then (around a decade back) pointed out the "too-to" structure in simple sentences and a "so-that" structure in complex sentences. He added that casual sentences like *I am so busy* or *I am too tired* are wrong and in each of those cases, we need a *very*, as in, *I am very busy* or *I am very tired*. His logic was that *so* or *to* need a *that* or *to* for meaningful completion, going by the examples above.

Is he correct? Does modern English deem *I am so busy* to be suitable or valid in formal contexts (say in written English or the English taught at schools)? Is *It is too/so hot and so we cannot go out without an umbrella* a valid compound sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it very likely that your English teacher was giving you ‘baby rules’: the sort of very broad rules you give a child (or learner) to prevent it from hurting itself before it is old enough (or knowledgeable enough) to understand subtle qualifications.

- In the case of *too*, your teacher was probably ‘protecting’ you from a very common learner’s error: using *too* as a simple intensive, equivalent to *very*.

  The ‘grown-up’ rule is that although it is quite true that *too* almost always involves a comparison of the sort you have in *too hot to go out*, this does **not** mean that the comparison must actually be expressed in every sentence in which you use *too*. The benchmark against which you are measuring may be entirely clear from the context.

  > Do you want to go for a walk?
  >   No, thanks, it’s ***too hot***.
- In the case of *so*, your teacher was probably trying to keep you from using intensive *so* in an inappropriate register. This use of *so* is colloquial and almost never found in formal or semi-formal registers such as you are typically called upon to employ in school essays. But in conversation (or dialogue, if you are writing fiction or a play or a script) it’s perfectly acceptable:

  > It is ***so hot*** today!

Such rules are pedagogically useful: they keep you focused on what you must learn and keep you from being distracted by all the million-and-one-things you might learn. But in language (as in pretty much everything else), once you reach a certain level of competence you may safely ignore classroom rules and instead follow the practice of writers and speakers you admire.

Answer (score 1):

> It is too hot to go out without an umbrella.

is OK.

> It is so hot that we cannot go out without an umbrella.

is also OK, but it intensifies *hot*, so you are meaning something like "it is excessively hot".

Regarding

> It is very hot and so we cannot go out without an umbrella.

Here, the two phrases *It is very hot* and *so we cannot go out without an umbrella* don't seem related and in any case it sounds strange. To link the phrases better, you could say:

> It is very hot, therefore we cannot go out without an umbrella.

I like *therefore* better than *so*, as it clearly indicates the second phrase is a result of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, both "I am so busy" and "It is too/so hot and so we cannot go out without an umbrella" are grammatical.

In the former "so" is an *intensifier*, however to avoid in academic writing.

In the latter either "so" or "too" are *intensifiers* and the second "so" serves as a linking adverb; depending on the context you can avoid the "and" there: "It is too/so hot. *So* we cannot go out without an umbrella."

Comment: snail, I'm sure you are right, but I like to give a little contribution to ELL as an answerer, too, even if I'm not a competent speaker. Thank you for your helpful comment.

Answer (score 0):

*So* means also "very; extremely." It is used, for example, in sentences similar to the following ones.

> I am so glad to see you.
>   Their attitude is so very English.
>   He sat there ever so quietly.

All those sentences are grammatically acceptable.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail? Were they ungrammatical at some point in time in the past, at least in formal writing?

Comment: @Sultan *So* has been an intensifier in English for over a thousand years.  It may not be *appropriate* in formal writing, but it isn't *ungrammatical*.

Comment: @Sultan, since 1980 grammarians use the term "pro-forms" to call "so" and other various words that substitute for others in a text. *So*, what past are you referring to? Maybe before 1985, that "so" usage was ungrammatical, but snail says no, though.

Comment: @snailplane: If you make that distinction between grammaticality and appropriateness, it is the latter about which I want to know.

Comment: @Sultan, it is not snail that make that distinction, but language and vocabulary. We all use English dictionary and *so* we can undarstand one with each other.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Yeah I see that. I want to be clear and conversant with the language of this community :)