# modal verbs in conditional clauses

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

> 1. If it should rain tomorrow, the party would not be held.
> 2. If I were to be young again, I would go to America to study.
> 3. If the sun were to rise in the west, I would not break my word.

(from a Korean English Grammar book)

[Present real conditional](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5030/first-second-and-third-conditional/5034#5034) (1) has its reference time in the future, and 
present unreal conditional (2) and (3) have their references in the present; so I guess 'would' in all three can be replaced by 'will.' Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three are unusual sentences. They would normally be expressed, at least in speech, as

1. If it rains tomorrow, the party won’t go ahead.
2. If I was young again, I’d go to America to study.
3. Even if the sun rose in the west, I still wouldn’t break my word.

Comment: What I wish to know is that in your 2 and 3; can 'would' be replaced by 'will'?

Comment: No, not without changing the verb in the ‘if’ clause like this:

'If I’m young again, I’ll go to America to study (unlikely).'

'Even if the sun rises in the west, I still won’t break my word.'