# Sentence choices and what difference they make

Tags: sentence-construction

It's way past the time I usually go for a jog at.

It's way past the time I usually go for a jog.

It's way past the time when I usually go for a jog.

Are all the above sentences grammatically correct?
What's the difference in their meaning, if there's any.

Comment: They're all syntactically acceptable, they all have the same meaning--and they all require that 'i' be capitalized.

Comment: Thanks.
Would you mind taking a look at another question?
If you don't, then : 

http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/sentence-choices-and-what-difference-they-make

Comment: The "at" in the first one is unnecessary... and dangling... I wouldn't suggest it. http://www.grammarly.com/handbook/grammar/prepositions/11/unnecessary-preposition/